# How to access Array Item With Variable perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, variables

I'm new to perl.

I'm facing a problem to access items in array by variable like other languages eg. C C++ Python3 JavaScript

Expected Way To Do Same In Perl:

```
print "@array[$var]" ;
```

It should print value of array at $var.

But It Gives Error. Any other way To do same.

Comment: Tip: The name of the language is "Perl", not "PERL". It's not an acronym.

Comment: If you actually have the backticks in your code, that will do [something else](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#%60STRING%60), remove those.

Comment: seems likely some part of the code you aren't showing us is wrong too; can you provide a complete runnable snippet of code and your expected output?

Comment: What's wrong with this code? It's pretty clear. How to access Array Item in perl. I don't know why this question is down voted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the value of an element of array `@array`, one uses `$array[$i]`.

This is documented in [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html).

And yes, `$array[$i]` can be used in double-quoted string literals.

```
print("$array[$i]\n");
```

---

Note that `@array[$i]` also works, but with a warning. You should only use `@array[...]` when there's the possibility of getting multiple elements.

```
$ perl -e'
   use strict;
   use warnings;
   my @array = "a".."z";
   my $var = 2;
   print "@array[$var]\n";
'
Scalar value @array[...] better written as $array[...] at -e line 7.
c

$ perl -e'
   use strict;
   use warnings;
   my @array = "a".."z";
   print "@array[2..4]\n";
'
c d e
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `$array[$var]`. What you wrote before was an incorrect way to access an array slice. If you need a slice, try this: `@array[$foo..$bar]`.

Comment: See a better answer by @ikegami instead.